# Excluding set of words from a listed dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, set

Suppose that I am having a **dictionary** as the following.

```
new_vocd = {'amazon': [668], 'flipkart': [34,56], 'myntra': [78,89,98], 'ebay': [876,768], 'microsoft': [67]}
```

I am having a exclude **set** with the following format.

```
exclude = {'amazon', 'microsoft'}
```

I want to exclude the words from `new_vocd` dictionary that are present in the exclude set. Is it possible using `set difference` option?

What are the other available ways? Any help is appreciated.

Expected output in terms of **dictionary**:

```
new_vocd = {'flipkart': [34,56], 'myntra': [78,89,98], 'ebay': [876,768]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_vocd = {k:v for k, v in new_vocd.items() if k not in exclude}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_vocd = {'amazon': [668], 'flipkart': [34, 56], 'myntra': [78, 89, 98], 'ebay': [876, 768], 'microsoft': [67]}
exclude = {'amazon', 'microsoft'}
for i in exclude:
    new_vocd.pop(i)
print(new_vocd)
```